# Laravel Assigning One to Many (?), Many to Many(?)

Tags: laravel, eloquent, relationship

I have two models
Stations
Operators

I am currently trying to "save" several Operators to a Station
but i want also to be able to "save" the same Operator to another Station.

Example:

```
+---------------------------------+
|   Station   |    Operator(s)    |
|---------------------------------|
| Munich      |   Lufthansa       |
|             |   KLM             |
|             |   Air Malta       |
|---------------------------------|
| Berlin      |   Lufthansa       |
|             |   KLM             |
|---------------------------------|
|-------    etc    ---------------|
|---------------------------------|
```

My Stations Table:

```
Schema::create('stations', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name', 100);
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

My Stations Model:

```
public function operators() {
    return $this->hasMany(Operators::class);
}
```

My Operators Table:

```
 Schema::create('operators', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name', 100)->unique();
        $table->string('email', 100);
        $table->boolean('notify')->default(false);
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

My Operators Model:

```
public function stations() {
    return $this->belongsTo(Stations::class);
}
```

Here i must say that i am creating the Station and trying to add the Operators:

In StationsController:

After receiving the Ids of the Operators and the Name of the Station:

```
$station = new Stations;
    $station->name = request('name');
    $station->save();
    foreach (request('operators') as $operator) {
        $tempOperator = Operators::find($operator);
        $station->operators()->associate($tempOperator)->save();
    }
```

The response is:

```
"Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::associate()"
```

I know there is something wrong with the relations but i cannot figure it out... Thank you in advance

Comment: there is no foreign key reference in the operators table in your migration. then how the relationship will work ?

Comment: @Naveen could you maybe elaborate please?

Answer (score 1):

Rollback your migration **php artisan migrate:rollback**

change your operators table migration like this,

```
Schema::create('operators', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name', 100)->unique();
        $table->string('email', 100);
        $table->boolean('notify')->default(false);
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

you have to create a mapping table like,

```
Schema::create('station_operators', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('stations_id')->unsigned();
        $table->integer('operators_id')->unsigned();
        $table->timestamps();

        $table->foreign('stations_id')->references('id')->on('stations');
        $table->foreign('operators_id')->references('id')->on('operators');
    });
```

Run migrate **php artisan migrate**

Your Stations Model:

```
public function StationOperators() {
    return $this->hasMany(StationOperators::class);
}
```

Your Operators Model:

```
public function StationOperators() {
    return $this->hasMany(StationOperators::class);
}
```

Your StationOperators Model:

```
public function Stations() {
    return $this->belongsTo(Stations::class);
}

public function Operators() {
    return $this->belongsTo(Operators::class);
}
```

For associate,

```
$station = new Stations;
    $station->name = request('name');
    $station->save();
    foreach (request('operators') as $operator) {
        // $tempOperator = Operators::find($operator);
        // $station->StationOperators()->associate($tempOperator)->save();

        $data = [
            'stations_id'   => $station->id,
            'operators_id' => $operator,
        ];

        $stationOperator = new \App\StationOperators();
        $stationOperator->save();
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your time! Still getting the same thing. Triple checked everything, seems i have it all the same.. one question though, should StationOperators Model be Model or Pivot?

Comment: should be a model

Comment: can you try to save StationOpertors with the two ids instead of associate

Answer (score 0):

You need an intermediate `StationsOperators` table.

Then try updating your operators model like this:

```
public function stations() {
    return $this->belongsToMany(Stations::class)->using(StationsOperators::class);
}
```

Remember:

> All custom models used to represent intermediate tables of relationships must extend the  Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Pivot class.

This is a Many-Many relation. You have to use pivot table.
@ref: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many

Comment: I miss something, try now

Comment: Created the Pivot StationsOperators. Still same result. Should it be empty or do I need to add something?

Comment: You have to create 2 fields to represent both ids (station and operator) and reference them in your migration file

Comment: Really appreciate your effort, would highly value if you could guide me through it.
I added this to StationsOperators Migration
    $table->integer('stations_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
            $table->foreign('stations_id')->references('id')->on('stations');
            $table->integer('operators_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
            $table->foreign('operators_id')->references('id')->on('operators');

Answer (score 0):

The associate method only available for belongsTo relationship, so it won't work for many to many relationship.

You can use the attach method for many to many, here is the example from laravel doc https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#updating-many-to-many-relationships